# Howto make multiple substring_index in mysql

Tags: mysql

Howto perform this in mysql

```
(substring_index(domain,'.',-3) OR (substring_index(domain,'.',-2)) IN (".implode(",", $domains)."))
```

When i run it with only

```
substring_index(domain,'.',-2) IN (".implode(",", $domains)."))
```

it works and

```
substring_index(domain,'.',-3) IN (".implode(",", $domains)."))
```

But the `OR` function makes the query return none

Solution found.
My problem was that my max_allowed_packet size was to small, and i got many entyes 40k at the IN statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add 2 statements

```
substring_index(domain,'.',-2) IN (".implode(",", $domains).") 
OR 
substring_index(domain,'.',-3) IN (".implode(",", $domains).")
```

Comment: I have tried this also but with no result, its like i cant perform 2 substring_index in one query

Comment: This is my full query.. SELECT count(*) AS count FROM (SELECT localip FROM dns_webfilter_access_log WHERE
    (
    ((substring_index(domain,'.',-3) OR (substring_index(domain,'.',-2)) IN (".implode(",", $domains)."))
    ) 
    AND user_ip='5.56.148.24' 
    AND (stamp > '$fradato') 
    AND (stamp < ADDDATE('$fradato', interval 1 day)) group by localip) AS data2

Comment: you should be able to !!

Comment: I tried to change to.. (
    (substring_index(domain,'.',-2) IN (".implode(",", $domains)."))
    OR 
    (substring_index(domain,'.',-3) IN (".implode(",", $domains)."))
    ) BUT no effekt

Comment: there is something wrong on the other part of query.. get the query and execute on mysql and see what u get.. one quick note SELECT count(*) AS count` to ` SELECT count(*) AS ` count  `

Comment: if i remove the * then i don't get any records at all. With or with out the or statement. When i have the * in count i get records from substring_index -2 or if i run it with -3

Comment: The problem must be in the IN, is it allowed to use more than one IN operation ??

Comment: The problem was my max_allowed_packet size was to little, after changing this value all was fine

Comment: ho this is weird. You must mention that in your question why SUBSTRING_INDEX did not work for long strings due to packet size. This would help others as well..

Comment: It's at the IN statement i got about 40k domains in that list, when i use i twice it would be 80k, and my value was set to 1m, i change it to 10m, and it fixed the problem..